# What is the difference between git reset and git revert?

Tags: git

Hi I am a newbie to git and I don't understand what is the basic difference between `git reset` and `git revert`. Does `git revert` reverts the merge being pushed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset)

Comment: Yes i got the solution here as well as to the link you mentioned after soon after I posted the question

Comment: `git revert` no files are deleted unlike the `git reset` command. Revert is often the better choice as a new SHA is created migrating all the files from the commit that you want to revert to. eg: 
`commit 123ab456 commit 223ab446 commit 223de446 commit 22356de44689 — — now is reverted to the information in commit 123ab456
` `git reset — hard` is destructive and removes all tracked files from the branch and you will not find these files either in the working directory or staging area. Safer are soft and mixed resets [More](https://sumisastri.medium.com/git-and-git-heads-f1f8c3d9c7df)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As far as I know, they are doing totally different thing.

`git revert` aimed to revert effects of previous commit.  For example,

```
A <- B <- C 
          ^ HEAD
```

If I found B I committed before is wrong, and I want to "undo" its change, `git-revert`-ing B will cause:

```
A <- B <- C <- B'
               ^ HEAD
```

for which `B'` is reversing the change done in B.

`git reset` is more straight-forward, it is simply setting the HEAD to a certain commit,

```
A <- B <- C 
          ^ HEAD
```

`git-reset`-ting to B will give you

```
A <- B <- C 
     ^ HEAD
```

Comment: Is there any ways to show the "tree map" 
(ex: A <- B <- C 
        ^ HEAD) 
 with command line ?
I really want to see it. thank you.

Comment: @Catbuilts something like `git log --graph`?

Comment: Does it do anything other then this? I noticed that after accidentally merged brach A into branch B, and then reverted the merge commit, then it was not possible anymore to merge A into B again. But only by reverting the revert commit.

Comment: git reset and push with -f can alter the repo commit history tree too, while git revert creates a new commit

Answer (score 4):

Git reset -->move the tip of a branch to a different commit. This can be used to remove commits from the current branch. It moves the branch backwards by commits.
Git Revert-->undoes a commit by creating a new commit. This is a safe way to undo changes, as it has no chance of re-writing the commit history.

Answer (score 3):

**git revert**: Undoes a change part of a commit to the local/origin repo by creating a new commit.

```
command: git revert <id>
```

**git reset**: Git reset will delete/undo changes which are committed in local repo. It undoes changes by 3 ways, –soft, –mixed, –hard. Where mixed is the default value.

Working Dir (coding ) -> Staging Area(Index) -> local Repo (git push)

```
git reset –soft/mixed/hard –HEAD~N -> mixed is default

git reset --soft HEAD~N   # will move file/changes  from local commit to staging area
git reset --mixed HEAD~N  #will move file/changes  from local commit to working directory
git reset --hard HEAD~N  #will delete file /changes from working directory
```