# What's the similarity & difference between git reset --hard HEAD~1 and git revert HEAD?

Tags: git, head, revert

I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

From what I can tell,  "git reset --hard HEAD~1" will remove the last commit, and that commit won't be seen in "git log".

And "git revert HEAD" will put me in nano where I can edit the commit message and also it saves the revert as a new commit in "git log"

Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/27032850/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28166547/3001761, ...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `git revert` will produce a **new** commit that **cancels** the effects of another given commit, replaying the negative version of its changeset. In particular, *git revert* won't do what *mercurial* would.

You can view it as a cancelation "a la Wikipedia": reverting something is assumed as a modification just like the others and can be dated.

`git reset`, however, will bring a branch pointer back to a given position. According to the parameter you specify, `--soft`, `--mixed` (default) or `--hard`, git will respectively modify only the branch pointer, the branch and the state of the index, or the branch, index and working directory content. This is therefore what's used to totally get rid of the tip of a branch but the command can act beyond this sole case.

Note that even if you unreference a commit using `git reset --hard` or something else, this commit will persist in the object collection until a garbage collector is run and be discarded only if it's old enough (typically three months).

So remember that if you've done that by accident, there's always a way to recover your commits if you don't wait too long.

Answer (score 1):

you are right.... they might give you the same "end result" in terms of what the working tree looks like... but the resulting history of the project is radically different.... If you asked me, if you just noticed that the last commit is not needed, just remove it from history altogether (`git reset --hard`). unless there's a *major* reason not to do it. Some people say that once it's published, it shouldn't be taken back... my take is that any seasoned git user knows how to rebase stuff with --onto and specifying a revision to *skip* so even if it's published, you should just remove it (letting other developers know what you did).... but that's just my assumption/opinion.

Answer (score 1):

See the otherwise excellent (and duplicate) Q&A at [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358035/1256452)  But we should start with something even more basic.

## Why do we use version control?

The *purpose* of a version control system is to save everything ever done, for all time.  Well, except when it isn't: sometimes the purpose is to save *some* of the things done for *all* time, *some* things for *some* time, and some things for a very short time.

The *way* that Git saves these is as complete snapshots, which we call *commits*, that also carry some extra information about the commit, which we call *metadata*.  The metadata includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, so that we can ask them *why* they made it, plus a log message, so that they  can tell us why they made it without us having to bother them.  The metadata in Git also includes the notion of a previous or *parent* commit.  By comparing the parent snapshot to this particular snapshot, Git can tell us what the person who made the commit *changed*.

With that in mind, we can look at these three Git verbs (I'm going to throw in `git checkout` too):

#### `git checkout` is to obtain something done at some time

We use `git checkout` to get one particular commit.  A commit is a snapshot someone made at some time.  Presumably that snapshot was good for some purpose.  We use `git checkout` to get that snapshot, exactly as it was made at that time, regardless of what our next purpose might be.

In Git, as a side effect of using `git checkout` with a *branch name*, we are now prepared to do *new* work.  But we can also use `git checkout` with a raw commit hash, after which new commits are ... well, a bit tricky.  (They're still possible, but Git calls this *detached HEAD* mode and you may not want to use it until you know a lot more about Git.)

The reason that `git checkout master`, for instance, works to get the *latest* commit on `master` is that every time we make a *new* commit on `master`, Git automatically updates our name `master` so that it *means* the newest such commit.  The newest commit remembers its parent, which used to be the newest.  That second-one-back commit remembers *its* parent, which was the newest when the one-back commit didn't exist either, and so on.

What this means is that the *name* `master` really just find the *last* commit, from which we find each earlier commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

where each uppercase letter stands in for a commit hash ID.  We say each commit *points to* its parent, and `master` *points to* the latest commit.

#### `git revert` is to back out a bad commit

Given that each commit records its parent, and that Git can therefore tell us what the person who made that commit *changed*, we can always have Git *undo* someone else's change (or even our own).  We pick a commit, view it as a change—which is how Git shows it to us when we use `git log -p` or `git show`—and discover that, hey, that change was *wrong*.  That change should be *backed out*, or “reverted”.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>The verb *revert* here is actually a bad choice.  The [most common English language definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revert) is almost always followed by the auxiliary word *to*, as in *revert to*, and it means to return to a former state.  But backing out some change doesn't necessarily return us to the old state!  We only return to our previous state if we back out the *most recent* change.

Other version control systems use the verb *backout*, which is better.  In any case, when we use this verb, Git makes a *new* commit, saving a new snapshot that's just like our previous checkout except that it has someone's change backed out.  Well, that is, Git makes this commit unless there's a *merge conflict*, but we'll ignore that possibility here.

---

#### `git reset` is ... well, muddled, but we can use it to *throw away* commits

Git's *reset* verb is extraordinarily complicated.  In one particular form, it does up to three things.  With other forms it does other things.  The one you've asked about in particular, `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, tells Git to:

1. Make the current branch *name*, whatever that is, point to the parent of the current commit.
2. Erase the current *index*—which we haven't described here, but *index*, *staging area*, and even *cache* are really just three names for the same thing in Git—and fill it in from the commit selected in step 1.
3. Remove all the *work-tree* files that went with the index before we reset it, and replace them with copies extracted from the commit selected in step 1 and copied into the index during step 2.

So if we had:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

we've changed the *name* `master` to point to `G`, shoving commit `H` up out of the way:

```
            H
           /
... <-F <-G   <-- master
```

The commit whose hash is `H` is now effectively *lost*, as if it had never been made.  It's still *in the repository*, it's just become hard to *find*.  In time, if we don't take any other steps to preserve it, commit `H` will really go away.

## Remember our purpose for commits

We want commits so that they save everything ever done for all time.  But sometimes, what we did—like, maybe, make commit `H`—was a mistake:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J--K--L   <-- master
```

If we made `H` a while ago and it's all embedded like this, it's hard to remove, because every commit is completely frozen, so to *remove* `H`, we have to *copy* `I` to a new and different commit `I'` that has `G` as its parent, then copy `J` to a new commit that has `I` as its parent, and so on:

```
          H--I--J--K
         /
...--F--G--I'-J'-K'  <-- master
```

Here it's easier to *revert* `H`, adding a new commit that undoes whatever we changed in `H`.  Commits `I` through `K` remain the same—probably slightly broken, but that's how they really were all along—and now we have a new commit `L` to undo what we did in `H`:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J--K--L   <-- master
```

But if `H` was pretty recent, we can just remove it entirely using `git reset --hard`.  We'll forget we ever made that mistake.  There's no need to tell anyone else.