# How to undo on selected commit

Tags: git

I want to undo on selected commit. Cause my team push different many files and many commits.

What I did was pull with deleted files. now my files gone also.

I tried this

```
git rebase -i 4dd0c29
git reset --hard undo
```

but nothings changed

Comment: Check this ones :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324638/reverting-specific-commits-from-git
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit 

More : https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/restore-repo-to-previous-revision

Comment: Read this it will explain how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command `git log` in project's main git directory to get recent commits. Most recent commit will be shown up first. It will also log commit number in long format. For example:

```
commit ed7cec151e25ea7f9e0d0563598ee9afd3170952
Author: xxx <xxx@email.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 28 17:25:51 2016 +0500
```

Then hard reset all changes using your commit ID:

```
git reset --hard ed7cec151e25ea7f9e0d0563598ee9afd3170952
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To revert a specific commit, use `git revert <commit>`

This will create a new commit where the content of `<commit>` has been reverted.

Comment: it gave me this error `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reflog` it will give you a list with log of the activities which changed `HEAD`. Find `HEAD@{id}` (where `id` is a number) which indicates at the head prior to `git pull` and then do `git reset --hard HEAD@{id}` (make sure replacing word `id` with the number of the `HEAD`)

Alternatively, you can do `git reset --hard HEAD^` this will revert your `HEAD` to previous state it was in prior to `git pull`.

Comment: where to find `id`?

Comment: Run `git reflog ` the `id` is of a form `HEAD@{number}`